# Does SQL Server have an equivalent of MySQL's JOIN USING?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to simplify my SQL Server joins; I'm tired of writing queries like this:

```
select
    SomeData
from
    SomeReallyLongParentTableName p
    join SomeReallyLongChildTableName c on p.SomeReallyLongParentTableNameID = c.SomeReallyLongParentTableNameID
```

I read that MySQL has a `using` clause you can use in joins to simplify them when the column names are the same, it looks something like this:

```
select
    SomeData
from
    SomeReallyLongParentTableName p
    join SomeReallyLongChildTableName c using SomeReallyLongParentTableNameID
```

This looks so much cleaner! But it doesn't work in SQL Server, unfortunately. Is there another syntax for this or am I just out of luck? Or maybe I need to use a newer version of SQL Server? (My SSMS is 2018, but the server itself is 2014, if I'm not mistaken.)

Comment: You're just out of luck, for now - even SQL Server 2019 still doesn't support this JOIN syntax

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. Thanks anyway! I wonder if Microsoft has some sort of discussion forum or issue tracker for SQL Server where I can suggest this idea, as they have an issue tracker on GitHub for the C# language?